# how i can know working of ajax with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

How can I learn Ajax or know how it works?
I have a task to load a page till footer.

Comment: have you tried http://learn.jquery.com/ ?

Comment: So what is your requirement.Elaborate it.

Comment: One way would be to start reading the documentation of jQuery.

Comment: To be honest, if you're a fresh web developer, they probably don't expect you to be able to do everything, I imagine they'd rather you ask for help if you don't know rather than sitting there not being able to do anything for 2 days. Or you could just dive into the documentation and try to learn it by yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would help you understand it better

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-load-in-and-animate-content-with-jquery/